# Recognize client IP in Mattermost

Tags: mattermost

I’m looking for a method to recognize client IP during an special interaction.
Actually I want to react to user based on his IP to check he is in office area or not.
Which one of these methods and help me? slash command? app? plugin or outgoing webhook?

I tried slash command, I found that the received POST message is always sent by server itself, so the IP is always the server IP.